# Permission denied when running a container (docker 1.12.5)

Tags: docker

I am trying to run an ElasticSearch container, on a newly-created VM with Docker 1.12.5 installed, but meet a `Permission Denied` exception. What puzzles me is that everything runs fine in an older VM of mine, with Docker 1.12.2. What am I missing?

**The exception**:

```
Exception in thread "main" SettingsException[Failed to open stream for url [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml]]; nested: AccessDeniedException[/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml];
Likely root cause: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromPath(Settings.java:1067)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.CliTool.<init>(CliTool.java:107)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.cli.CliTool.<init>(CliTool.java:100)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.BootstrapCLIParser.<init>(BootstrapCLIParser.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:242)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
```

**The system**:

- Windows 10, with VirtualBox installed,
- a XUbuntu 16.04 image, with a shared host folder containing the Dockerfile and the elasticsearch.yml configuration file.

**The Docker file**:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre

ENV VERSION 2.4.1

RUN groupadd -r elasticsearch && useradd -r -g elasticsearch elasticsearch
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 46095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && echo 'deb http://packages.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/2.x/debian stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch.list
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends elasticsearch=$VERSION \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PATH /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /usr/share/elasticsearch
RUN set -ex \
    && for path in \
        ./data \
        ./logs \
        ./config \
        ./config/scripts \
    ; do \
        mkdir -p "$path"; \
        chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch "$path"; \
    done

COPY config ./config
VOLUME /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
VOLUME /usr/share/elasticsearch/logs

EXPOSE 9200 9300
USER elasticsearch
CMD elasticsearch
```

Aside the Dockerfile, lives the **following file structure**:

```
- config
  - elasticsearch.yml
```

As the image works on another VM, I believe its configuration should be right. I do not think the problem comes from ElasticSearch either, as I seem to have another image having the same issue (H2). I'm beginner-level with both Docker and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the file permissions after you copy the config in:

```
COPY config ./config
RUN chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
```

You could also create and `chown` the `/usr/share/elasticsearch` directory as root then complete the rest of the steps dealing with the contents of `/usr/share/elasticsearch` as `USER elasticsearch`

Comment: Thank you. Setting the permissions after the copy worked. Don't know why it worked on my previous VM, but am happy right now. Cheers.

Comment: Permission mappings from windows into unix are always a bit messed up. The only time you can trust the source is when it is a linux file system so it's best to just set what you need in the docker file so it can't go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

change your volume permissions to 777 example:- chmod 777 /path/to/volume

**do not give recursive permissions**